# Negative sign near (stopping) time value

Tags: stochastic-processes, notation, stochastic-calculus

I cannot figure out the meaning of the negative sign in the following examples, where $\mathcal({F}_t)$ is a filtration,$(M_t)$ is $\mathcal({F}_t)$-martingale $(M_t)$ (or simply a random process), a stopping time T.

i) $\mathcal({F}_{0-}) = \mathcal({F}_0)$

ii) $M_{t-}$ and $M_{T-}$

Answer (score 2):

That notation means a time right before the index in question, a usual language for a limit. In other words, if you are saying $F_{t-} =F_t$, you really mean to say that
$$
\lim_{s \to t^-} F_s = F_t,
$$
or alternatively, that $F_t$ is left-continuous.

Comment: How do we read it? I mean is there a specific way, or we just t minus?

Comment: @Cadenza perhaps "before $t$" or just $t-$ as you propose